# Is it possible to append Class objects to "__all__"?

Tags: python

`Current Project Structure`

```
---src
 |__controllers
 |  |__ prediction.py
 |   
 |__regression
    |__ __init__.py
    |__ deep_learning.py
```

The deep_learning.py contains a class where I am initializing a model.

#### Goal

My goal is to use the class object from deep_learning in prediction.py in the controller directory.

---

#### Current Code for __init__.py

I have tried adding the following code inside the __init__.py inside the regression directory:

```py
from deep_learning import predict
future_predict = predict()
__all__.append('future_predict')
```

Here the predict is the name of the class that is contained inside the deep_learning.py.

---

#### Current Code for prediction.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_from_directory

@app.route('/<filename>', methods=["POST"])
def predict(filename):
    print("something: ", future_predict)
    return send_from_directory(app.config['IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH'], filename)
```

---

#### Error

However, I have not been successful with using `future_predict` object inside prediction.py.
The error: `NameError: name 'future_predict' is not defined`

Comment: You have defined ``future_predict``, but the error shows you are using ``futurePredict``. Mind the spelling.

Comment: The different spelling suggests the code shown is not the code you are running. Does your real code use both spellings? Does your real code actually attempt to import either of ``future_predict`` or ``futurePredict``? Please [edit] your code to include the full traceback and matching code. See the [mcve] page how to best help use help you.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited the code. the article on minimal reproducible example really helped. Can I export all the files and the classes inside the __init__.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several misunderstandings:

- `__all__` is a way to define what is importable
- you still need to import those symbols!
- you need an `__init__.py` also in your `controllers` package

Usually, Python projects, which make use of a `src` top level directory, have a structure like this:

```
❯ tree src/
src/
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── package_1
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── package_2
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── package_3
        └── __init__.py

4 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: How do I import that symbols in my case? Do I need to put those imports inside __init__.py?

Comment: I have added the __init__.py files in all the directories. I am still not able export it. I tried appending to the __all__. I am still not able to use the class object or the class anywhere in the project.

Comment: Unfortunately, weekends are family time. I am not able to answer you soonish. Maybe this article sheds some light into the problem: https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/ All the best!